# VS Code error: Unable to write to folder settings because no resource is provided

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I start VS Code, I get the error 'Unable to write to Folder Settings because no resource is provided.' How can I identify what's causing this and resolve it?

VS Code: 1.57.1
code-server: 3.11.0
OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Extensions:
Python: v2021.6.944021595
Jupyter: v2021.6.99